# Python Bottle CORS enabled but not working

Tags: python, angularjs, apache, cors, bottle

Hi everyone I'm new with python bottle and I'm developing an API to be consumed by Angularjs. When I try to use the endpoints it shows me the next error in the browser console:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load build.my.domain.com:8001/api/ldap/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin build.my.domain.com:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

I currently enabled the bottle CORS:

## the decorator

def enable_cors(fn):

```
def _enable_cors(*args, **kwargs):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Accept, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token'

    if request.method != 'OPTIONS':
        # actual request; reply with the actual response
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

return _enable_cors
```

Even after make the call the back shows me the next log:

http://build.my.domain.com:8000
10.30.16.70 - - [05/Mar/2016 12:58:07] "OPTIONS /api/ldap/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 0

http://build.my.domaincom:8000
10.30.16.70 - - [05/Mar/2016 12:58:07] "OPTIONS /api/ldap/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 200 0

but I stills the errors appears

XMLHttpRequest cannot load build.my.domain.com:8001/api/ldap/authenticate. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin build.my.domain.com:8000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: You haven't shown enough code; can you show how you're using the decorator?

Comment: Have you set up a callback of this function with `@hook('after_request')`?